# HTTP_USER_AGENT script

Tags: django

Can someone explain this script?

```
 device = {}

    ua = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '').lower()

    if ua.find("iphone") > 0:
        device['iphone'] = "iphone" + re.search("iphone os (\d)", ua).groups(0)[0]
```

I know it gets the user agent and the first bit searches the string for iphone. but

why > 0?
and what is the second like doing?

Comment: can you provide the full script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a python guy but I am almost sure that `.find()` returns position where the string "iphone" occurs.

So if it was found, it will be >= 0.